# D3Js Multiple trees with one json as input

Tags: d3.js, tree

I'm using d3-stratify to display my data as a hierarchical tree. My data is setup in a json file. I may have the case of multiple trees in my json file but d3-stratify cannot create multiple trees (it cannot have multiple roots).

I tried to create a "fake root" node which link to my actual real roots, it works correctly but by doing this I have a big tree and my trees are linked by this fake node. I don't know how to do to get real separate multiple trees in this case.

Also I would like to use d3-stratify because it aligns the tree on the last node.

What do you recommend ?

Thanks.